# What A Round Riddle

Tags: riddle

> What a short word I am in this world
>
> Only a few letters long
>
> But many people still mistake me for my twin brother
>
> We may sound the same, but trust me,
>
> Our meanings are very different
>
> Are you still confused? Then let me help you with a few hints
>
> Add a letter to me and you can find my twin brother
>
> Add 4 letters to me and I may have to wear an eyepatch
>
> Now tell me, what am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are:

> **Pi**

What a short word I am in this world
Only a few letters long

> **Pi** is only 2 letters long

But many people still mistake me for my twin brother
We may sound the same, but trust me,
Our meanings are very different

> **Pi** is often confused with **pie** because they are homophones

Are you still confused? Then let me help you with a few hints
Add a letter to me and you can find my twin brother

> Adding 'e' to **pi** gives us **pie**

Add 4 letters to me and I may have to wear an eyepatch

> Adding 'rate' gives us **pirate**

Now tell me, what am I?

> You are **pi**

Comment: Correct! Was this too easy??

Comment: To be honest, as soon as I read 'eye patch' I knew the answer had to be pirate. It's a great riddle though! :)

Comment: Thanks. Will try to improve in future riddles :)

Answer (score 0):

You are

> in

What a short word *I am in* this world.
Only a few letters long

> In is only 2 letters long

But many people still mistake me for my twin brother
We may sound the same, but trust me,
Our meanings are very different

> In is often confused with inn because they are homophones

Are you still confused? Then let me help you with a few hints
Add a letter to me and you can find my twin brother

> Adding 'n' to in gives us inn

Add 4 letters to me and I may have to wear an eyepatch

> Adding 'bl' and 'ds' gives us blinds

Now tell me, what am I?

> You are in

Answer (score 0):

> Answer is PI. Adding another letter to it becomes PIE which sounds the same.

Comment: >! Adding an answer which has already has been provided could possible get you downvoted. Please check the previous answers before posting yours. Also, you should hide your answer in a spoiler.